# Is it possible to run a node JS program in a console-like environment?

Tags: node.js

What I want is very simple, to run code while typing, just like enter `node` and run things like this:

```
% node
Welcome to Node.js v17.0.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> var a=5; var b=6;
> console.log(a+b);
11
```

But in this case, I have to copy and paste my code again and again.

Is it possible to "include" the code from an eternal `.js` file, then let me stay in the console-like environment to run the code?

Store these in the `app.js`:

```
var a=5;
var b=6;
function addNumber(x,y){console.log(x+y);}
```

In node console:

```
% node
Welcome to Node.js v17.0.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> include "app.js" //- This is what I'm looking for
> addNumber(a,b);
11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `require` files in the REPL just as easily as you can in a standard Node script.

For example, inside a directory, create a file, `foo.js`:

```
module.exports = () => 'foo';
```

And inside that directory, enter Node:

```
PS D:\Directory> node
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.6.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const foo = require('./foo');
undefined
> console.log(foo())
foo
undefined
>
```

`require('./foo')` will return the exports of the `foo` file in the same directory.

`require('../foo')` will return the exports of the `foo` file in the parent directory.

Absolute paths work too. And so on.